# How to model spherical corners

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am looking to recreate the object shown below but with a better topology. However, I cannot work out how I would model such a shape.

[image: Spherical Corner][image]

The important details I am trying to achieve is having the spherical corner be "tight" meaning the spherical curvature all happens around a section that terminates across 1 point on either side of the corner (green cross):

The closest method so far is the following:

## Method

1. Select corner edge and bevel
2. Bevel the edges around the corner

[image: Bevel step 1][image: Bevel step 2]

### Outcome

This is close, but it is very difficult to control the start and end point of the spherical section, because the end result depends on the depth of the first bevel.

The first bevel needs to be long enough to not cause the second bevel to collapse at the edges:

[image: Bevel collapse][image]

And even if you do get it close enough, there is always 2 extra segments that cause it not to be tight:

Is there a more precise and reliable method to achieve this spherical corner shape?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand your goal, you can do this in one go.

1. Select all outer edges (even the horizontal one)
2. Bevel them with *Clamp Overlap* checked (Shortcut: <kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Merge double vertices (<kbd>Alt+M</kbd> > by distance)

[image]

Comment: Ah I hadn't even thought of including all edges like that! That is it! Do you have a way of snapping it to the middle?

Comment: AHA! I found it, the key is the setting of `Clamp Overlap` which I couldn't see as I am in 2.83 and the interface has changed. Then the `Merge by Distance` to get rid of the overlapping verticies. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Good luck with your project.